# Calling SignalR hub methods from a different project

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

In the solution I have a SignalR Server hub that users connect to. In the other project of the Server I want to call the Client methods. However SignalR Hub is not static, and if I declare a new SignalR hub class then it will have different connections then the original hub.

How can I reference the original SignalR hub in a different project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<YourHubClass>()` on which you can call `Clients`.

Comment: I have a hub called TestHub and it has a public method SendCall. When I do: GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TestHub>().SendCall() I get an error: 'IHubContext' does not contain a definition for 'SendCall'

Comment: I guess you can't call hub methods. You can only call the Clients methods directly.